# Annotate ggplot error bar

Tags: r, annotations, ggplot2

I have been using R just for past 3 days and have got  most of the code below  through research which I have adapted to suit my needs.  It works perfectly well.  I want to be able to label/annotate the error bars  on the standard errors with ( B, A*,  A,  A) respectively.  Below is the working code;

```
cat<-rep(c("E","F","G","H"),each=12)
var2=rnorm(48,10)*(rep(rpois(4,.2),each=12)/8+1)
ds<-data.frame(cat,var2)
lbls<- c("B","A*","A","A")

stderr <- function(x){sqrt(var(x,na.rm=TRUE)/length(na.omit(x)))}
lowsd <- function(x){return(mean(x)-stderr(x))}
highsd <- function(x){return(mean(x)+stderr(x))}
cols <- c("red", "yellow", "green", "blue")

ggplot(ds,aes(cat,var2, fill=cat))+
ggtitle("Asem beba Dabi")+
xlab("Soil Sample Sites\n\n Fig 1 shows...") + ylab("Mass or Water(mg)") +
# first layer is barplot with means
stat_summary(fun.y=mean, geom="bar", position="dodge", colour="white")+
# second layer overlays 
stat_summary(fun.y=mean, fun.ymin=lowsd, fun.ymax=highsd, geom="errorbar", position="dodge",color = 'blue', size=.5)
```

This is the bit I  am struggling with

```
geom_text(aes(label=lbls), position=position_dodge(width=0.9), vjust=-0.25)
```

This is a school assignment and any help will be highly appreciated

Comment: I want to  add   lbls<- c("B","A*","A","A")   The markings  B, A*, A and A on the four bars respectively

Comment: geom_text(aes(label=lbls), position=position_dodge(width=0.9), vjust=-0.25)  but nothing shows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't see labels because labels are not in the same data frame as x and y values. One solution would be to use the same `stat_summary()` with `geom="text"` and then adjust position with `vjust=`.

```
ggplot(ds,aes(cat,var2, fill=cat))+
  stat_summary(fun.y=mean, geom="bar", colour="white")+
  stat_summary(fun.y=mean, fun.ymin=lowsd, fun.ymax=highsd, 
                   geom="errorbar", color = 'blue', size=.5)+
  stat_summary(fun.y=mean,geom="text",label=lbls,vjust=-2)
```

Comment: I am wondering what is meant by no research effort to have my question down voted. I am also wondering how somebody has been able to assist with a solution and yet been branded as unclear. I think the easiest way out not to help is to tag a question unclear and vote it down